# Abbreviations Using Uima Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I tried to tag abbreviations in some files using Uima Ruta. I used a simple script as below but is not working for certain abbreviations.

My algorithm goes something like this;
1. Split abbreviation into letters/numbers (ATM -> A,T,M . IC3 -> I,C,3)
2. Convert numbers into letters (I,C,3 -> I,C,C,C)
3. Read current sentence and match letters to words (stop words may/may not be included)

But I don't know how to achieve the same in Ruta. Where can I look for such looping and control structures ?

Sample Input:

```
  The National Academies of Science, Engineering, and Medicine (NAS)
  registered nurses (RNs)
  Licensed practical nurses (LPNs)
  Asian/Pacific Islander Americans (APIAs)

  Crime&Investigation Network (CI) 
  Internet Crime Complaint Center (“IC3”)
  Practice Management <PM>
```

Script:

```
CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW LParen CAP RParen{-> MARK(DZC_ABBREVIATIONS, 1, 12)};
CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW{-PARTOF(DZC_ABBREVIATIONS)}  LParen CAP RParen{-PARTOF(DZC_ABBREVIATIONS) -> MARK(DZC_ABBREVIATIONS, 1, 12)};
CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (EnglishStopWord?|SPECIAL?)? CW (LParen CAP SW?  RParen){-PARTOF(DZC_ABBREVIATIONS) ->  MARK(DZC_ABBREVIATIONS, 1, 11)};
```

Untagged ABBREVIATIONS:

```
Chronic Kidney Disease in Children (CKiD)
Society of Intercultural Education, Training, and Research (SIETAR)
The National Academies of Science, Engineering, and Medicine (NAS)
Internet Crime Complaint Center (“IC3”)
```

Comment: This is maybe not solved easily in Ruta. The only real control structure is the BLOCK construct (combined IF, LOOP, also allows recursion). You need to create annotations within the CAP annotations. This can be achieved with the simple regular expression rules applied only within the CAP annotations. You can multiply the parts (by pasring the NUM with PARSE and store the result in a INT variable)  and store them in a STRINGLIST in oder to check the beginning of the previous words, e.g., with the string functions in ruta-core-ext or with REGEX using a STRING variabe..